# cffi's foreign-alloc with list containing a defconstant

Tags: c, common-lisp, cffi

I'm trying to do:

```lisp
(defconstant x 1)
(cffi:foreign-alloc :int :initial-contents  '(x 99))
```

but I get an error message:

```
The value X is not of type (SIGNED-BYTE 32).
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

It is very important that I can define this:

```lisp
(x 99) ; x does need to be a defconstant equaling 1
```

as a pointer for the code I am writing.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
(cffi:foreign-alloc :int :initial-contents (list x 99))
```

`'(x 99)` means that `(x 99)` is not evaluated, so its a list containing the symbol `x` and the number `99`

`(list x 99)` is a function, so `x` is evaluated and replaced by its value `1` and then a list is created with contents `1 and 99`.